# Modifying Game of Life code so that the lattice can be seeded with life forms

Tags: programming, recursion, cellular-automata

I want to modify Game of Life code so that the lattice can be seeded with one or two new life forms like:

```
glider[x_, y_] := {{x, y}, {x+1, y}, {x+2, y}, {x+2, y+1}, {x+1, y+2}}

snake[x_, y_] := {{x, y}, {x, y+1}, {x+1, y}, {x+2, y+1}, {x+3, y+1}, {x+3, y}}
```

I don't know how to modify my code to put above code! I'd be grateful if you could help.

Here is my code:

```
Life[n_, t_] := 
     Module[{initConfig, Moore, update, LiveConfigs, DieConfigs},

initConfig = Table[Random[Integer], {n}, {n}];

LiveConfigs = 
    Join[Map[Join[{0}, #] &, Permutations[{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]], 
    Map[Join[{1}, #] &, Permutations[{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]], 
    Map[Join[{1}, #] &, Permutations[{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]]];

DieConfigs = 
    Complement[Flatten[Map[Permutations, 
  Map[Join[Table[1, {#}], Table[0, {(9 - #)}]] &, Range[0, 9]]], 1], LiveConfigs];

Apply[(update[##] = 1) &, LiveConfigs, 1]; 
Apply[(update[##] = 0) &, DieConfigs, 1];


Moore[func__, lat_] := 
  MapThread[func, 
     Map[RotateRight[lat, #] &, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1},
           {1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}}], 2];

FixedPointList[Moore[update, #] &, initConfig, t]]
```

Comment: Hi ! Please, refer to the help centre and read more about proper code formatting practices.

Comment: It's utterly strange to ignore how to modify your own code.

Comment: @belisarius: I don't think "be ignorant of" is one of the meanings of the verb "ignore"...

Comment: @Rahul One of these days I'll have to return to my English class ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to seed the game of life with a glider, using the built-in game of life `CellularAutomaton` and the OPs glider (starting at 10,10).

```
glider[x_, y_] := {{x, y}, {x + 1, y}, {x + 2, y}, {x + 2, y + 1}, {x + 1, y + 2}};
gameOfLife = {224, {2, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}, {1, 1}};
board = SparseArray[Flatten[{Thread[glider[10, 10] -> 1], {50, 50} -> 1}, 1]]; 
Dynamic[ArrayPlot[board = Last[CellularAutomaton[gameOfLife, board, {{0, 1}}]]]]
```

[image]

The glider starts at {10,10}.

Comment: @kuba -- thanks for the picture!